# Patenting a feature-add invention that requires slight modification of the base-invention

Tags: patentability

Let's suppose that you have invented a product that is a feature addon to an existing invention.

However, in order to attach the addon invention to the original base-invention, the base-invention needs to be modified slightly.

Is this feature-addon invention still patentable?

For example, in order to attach the feature addon invention, one would need to build a quick release buckle onto the base-invention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems to be about a practical issue regarding commercialization. Those issues do not affect patentability. Patentability is not constrained by practicality of implementation or business arrangements that might need to be worked out to have an easy to use product.

However, the way you intend to commercially exploit the invention might cause claims to be drafted in a specific way. A claim to a new car mirror could be worded to include the car. “A car having a mirror that . . .” Or it could be to a mirror configured to be a component of a car or attached to a car.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean. Do you mean that it is in fact acceptable that the base-invention is modified?